# How to add an offset for ReactNative SectionList items viewability

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I have a ReactNative application with a SectionList. There's an absolute positioned header over the list which contains the names of the sections.
When scrolling this list, I need to update which section is currently scrolled.

**Here is my code:**

```
const handleChangeSelectedIndexWithScroll = ({ viewableItems }) => {
  if (!viewableItems || viewableItems.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  // Get which section is visible on the screen
  const visibleSectionsId = viewableItems.map(
    (viewableItem) => viewableItem.section.index
  );

  // Say that the currently scrolled section is the first one that has any visible item.
  // By doing this, if the first section has any single visible item, it will be the one selected
  setCurrentSectionScrolled(Math.min(...visibleSectionsId));
};

<SectionList
        ref={recipeDetailsRef}
        sections={data}
        onViewableItemsChanged={handleChangeSelectedIndexWithScroll}
/>
```

**The problem:**
With the absolute header, the scroll isn't well reflected because RN considers that the section's items are visible on screen when in fact, they can be hidden behind the header.

**Screenshot**
[image]
On this image, you can see that the current selected section is "Ingredients" when in fact, we're already on "Materiels", because behind the absolute header, there's still an Ingredient visible to RN

**Considered solutions:**

- I know about the viewabilityConfig but it doesn't work because each item of the section **can be** small, and two or three items can be hidden behind the header. It means that even if I say that 90% of the item should be visible to be considered as visible, it won't solve the problem.
- Change the `handleChangeSelectedIndexWithScroll` function to say that multiple items should be visible for the section to be considered as visible. It won't work because a section can have a single item, or have multiple high items.

This is why I was wondering if there was a single solution to say to RN: "Please consider that there is an offset of 50px for this list", so that they don't consider visible items if they are in this offset

Thanks

Comment: Want to see more of the list while scrolling?

Comment: I edited with a screenshot so that you can understand better

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the active item, you can use the following method.

```js
const handleChangeSelectedIndexWithScroll = ({ changed , viewableItems }) => {
  if (!viewableItems || viewableItems.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  const sectionIndex = viewableItems.length - changed.length

  setCurrentSectionScrolled(sectionIndex);
};
```

Comment: It's not about the selected item, it's about the selected section